# How to make Shell script style arguments passing with argparse in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have a python parsing arguments like below:

**Code:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Args test')
    parser.add_argument('-myarg1', '--myarg1', type=str, dest='myarg1', required=True, help='Help yourself')
    parser.add_argument('-myarg2', '--myarg2', type=str, dest='myarg2', default=' ', help='Help yourself')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.myarg1)
    print(args.myarg2)
```

Above works if I call the script like below:

```
python myargs.py -myarg1 something -myarg2 somethingelse
```

But it does not work if I call it like below:

```
python myargs.py -myarg1 something -myarg2
```

And throws the below error obviously because it expects caller to pass value for the second argument.

```
usage: myargs.py [-h] -myarg1 MYARG1 [-myarg2 MYARG2]
myargs.py: error: argument -myarg2/--myarg2: expected one argument
```

**Quesion:**
I understand the reason for python complaining about it above. But, I want the user of my python script to be able to call the second argument with just saying `-myarg2` or `--myarg2` without specifying the type. Just like shell script style. Is it possible to do it with `argparse`?

I am using python 2.7 and above.

Comment: What is the expected value type of myarg2?

Comment: I updated the value type. Its str. Both arguments are string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You can use the `action="store_true"` attribute to turn an argument into a Boolean (flag).

```py
parser.add_argument('-myarg2', '--myarg2', dest='myarg2', action="store_true", help='Help yourself')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.myarg2) # True if "python myargs.py -myarg2", False if "python myargs.py"
```

#### Edit

If you want the user to be able to pass an optional argument to the `myarg2` flag, you need to use the `nargs='?'` attribute. You also need to define a `default` attribute which will be called if the flag isn't used, and a `const` attribute which will be called if the flag is used but without arguments.

```py
parser.add_argument('-myarg2', '--myarg2', dest='myarg2', nargs='?', const="no value", default='no flag', help='Help yourself')
```

Comment: But if she wants to pass a str argument this will result raise an error

Comment: Indeed, I've modified my answer to take care of this case

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call the argument flag without a value. If you want the value to be an empty string do -

`python myargs.py -myarg1 something -myarg2  ' '`

Comment: I know that I can pass ' ' or ''. It works but I wanted to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use --myarg and interpret it as true (otherwise it is false) you need to use

```
parser.add_argument("-myarg2", "--myarg2", action="store_true")
```

Comment: But if she wants to pass a `str` argument this will result raise an error

Comment: @Lior Cohen good point. Strange that python does not give a way to pass string or not pass a string. But if this is the constraint in python, then I would have to live with it.

Comment: Ok. Just one question. action='store_false' makes it false?

Comment: How to check if user has passed an input or not?

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg Indeed, `action="store_false"`will make it false, and `action="store_const"` will make it the value of the `const` attribute. You can learn more [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action)